# Convert from varchar into date in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

This looks easy solution but I can't seem to figure out as to why this is not working for me. I have a column that has data like this:

```
DateField
----------
12/16/2016
11/06/2016
```

All I want to do is to convert from `varchar` into a `date` column, but I am getting this error:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Here is my simple query:

```
select convert (date, DateField) as convertedField 
from myTable
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with the two examples you have given. There are some bad dates in your table which cannot be converted to date. Which version of `SQL SERVER` you are using ?

Comment: i am using 2012

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the two examples you have given. There are some bad dates in your table which cannot be converted to date.

Use `TRY_CONVERT` function for bad dates it will return `NULL`

```
select TRY_Convert(date,DateField)
From myTable
```

You should always store dates in `DATE/DATETIME` datatype.

If you want to see the records which cannot be converted to date then

```
select DateField
From myTable
Where TRY_Convert(date,DateField) IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

If working with a specific date format like `mm/dd/yyyy` You can specify it in `Convert()` function like the following

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,DATAFIELD,101)
```

If it still is not working, use `TRY_CONVERT()` to get which rows are throwing this exception:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TBL 
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(DATETIME, DATAFIELD, 101) IS NULL
```

This will return rows that cannot be converted

`TRY_CONVERT()` will return `NULL` if conversion failed

Read more about *DateTime* formats here:
[SQL Server CONVERT() Function tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp)

Read [TRY_CONVERT MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx)

Comment: Since when do you HAVE to specify a style with Convert()?

Comment: I changed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the format of date time while formatting. The date in your table is currently in U.S format so you should pass the third argument 101 in your convert function.

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,[DateField],101) FROM myTable;
```

Working Fiddle here http://rextester.com/NYKR49788

More info about date time style here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Comment: i did exactly what you suggested but still getting the same error

Comment: is all your dateField value in the same format or do they have different format

Comment: The default format of the Date is mm-dd-yyyy. yours is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @enigma6205 that is why is used the third parameter in convert function `101` to specify the format is U.S date format.

Comment: Since when do you HAVE to specify a style with Convert()?

Comment: Since when do you HAVE to specify a style with Convert()?